# Infinite recursion using lambda in python

Tags: python, recursion, lambda

I have a class. This class contains a function. I want to change this function in the same way every once in a while. If I use lambda I get infinite recursion. I understand why I get this, I want to find an elegant solution.

```
def func(s):
    return  1 # some not interesting function

class cls: # a class

    def __init__(self , f):
    self.f = f

c = cls(func)
c.f = lambda x: c.f(x) + 1 #  i want c.f to return c.f(x) + 1
print(c.f(1)) # causes infinite recursion
```

I don't want to do

```
c.f = lambda x: func(x) + 1
```

because I want to change `c.f` in the same way more than once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The infinite recursion is happening because inside the lambda function, `c.f` is resolved at call-time, so it's already the "new" `lambda` function instead of the original function passed to `cls.__init__`.

You *could* do something like this:

```
c.f = lambda x, f=c.f: f(x) + 1
```

Since the argument default is evaluated at the time the lambda function is created, it will be the original function on the class.

Comment: This works, thanks. I can't see what this is doing though. Care to give explanations\ references?

Comment: @YairDaon -- I did explain ... `f=c.f` gets evaluated when the lambda function is _created_, not when it is called, so the `f` that gets passed to the function is `c.f` (the original).